# Importing mysql.connector and then converting to .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Why is'nt

```
    >>>import mysql
```

importing the mysql database?

Also , i have imported mysql.connector() [>>>import mysql.connector()] while converting .py files to exe through pyintaller, how can i make the connector work in a machine/PC that doesn't have MySql installed?

Comment: I have completely  reframed my question. Please remove it from hold if you feel that it is not off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Pyinstaller is only for Python scripts. It just converts your Python script and any Python third-party packages to an executable program that doesn't require a Python installation.

If your application depends on something non-Python, like MySQL, then that will need installed on the target machine too.

Comment: Thank you. But what else could be done other than installing mysql on the target machine??